# SQL - Find person with latest date

Tags: mysql, sql, date, find

I'm having some trouble being able to find the persons SSN who most recently started an event.

This is my table:

```
Shootingseries (PersonSSN, Eventdate)
```

So, I need to find the SSN who most recently started an event.

What I have so far is:

```
select PersonSSN, max(Eventdate)
from Shootingseries
group by Evendate DESC LIMIT 1;
```

This works technically, but if there's two persons with the same Eventdate it does not display that other person aswell with LIMIT 1. Any sort of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This query will return all PersonSSN that have the most recent eventdate:

```
SELECT
  PersonSSN
FROM
  Shootingseries
WHERE
  Eventdate = (SELECT MAX(Eventdate) FROM Shootingseries)
```

Comment: @ErikÅstrand you're welcome :) pls don't forget to accept the answer if you find it useful and if you wish... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT PersonSSN 
FROM Shootingseries 
HAVING Eventdate = MAX(Eventdate)
```

This will work on mySQL

Answer (score 0):

> This works technically, but if there's two persons with the same Eventdate it does not display that other person aswell with LIMIT 1. Any sort of help is appreciated.

Well your PersonSSN column has to be unique for the group by to work on each individual PersonSSN.